# The API type of the received token in not Text. Please use a subscription to Translator Text API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator, azure-marketplace, bing-translator-api

I'm getting an Argument Exception message using the Microsoft Translator Text API.

I am using the Access Keys generated from Azure Portal for my Translator Speech API resource.

I am also able to retrieve the access token successfully as shown in the image below.

[Issue Token OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TaXr.png)

However, when I request for translation at https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate I'm receiving the message

> The API type of the received token in not Text. Please use a subscription to Translator Text API

as shown in the image below.

[Argument Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjQy4.png)

I have already tried the C# Bot Translator sample from https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/BotTranslator, with the same results (same error).

What could be the problem? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake, I've been using a "Translator **Speech** API" subscription key instead of the "Traslator **Text** API" key that is required.